# Is there any difference between ex vs ex.ToString? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, try-catch

I am talking about `Try ... Catch ex as Exception ....  End Try`

If I pass exception to Error Logger, shall I pass exception object (ex) or `ex.ToString` ? Would I lose any information by passing `ex.ToString`?

Basically I was arguing with my manager, that ex.ToString should be excatly the same as passing ex as an object. M I wrong or right ?

Comment: Definitely you are wrong.. One more thing, never argue with your manager.. :D

Comment: Use strings at the very last stage where you want to diplay,print or log something. The logger should decide when and how to convert the exception to a string.

Comment: Haha .. well ..  I said argue but I just argued very politely :D

Comment: Thanks Tim .. now I understand but I am struggling to decide which one to pick as the answer :D

Comment: @LaurenceNyein: If there are multiple answers that are equally good I generally sort by oldest and choose the first one that got posted. Its the fairest way to do it. Though of course +1 all the ones that you found helpful.

Comment: @Chris: If he is going to +1 all the helpful answers, then I am also going to post an answer here.. ;) :D

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: fair point. Though my way of looking at it is that if you at this stage just posted the same thing as somebody else then that's not actually helpful since somebody already posted it. :) I'm generally happy to give leeway of a few minutes to take into account time taken for people to write answers though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An exception object is different from calling `.ToString()` on the object itself.  It depends on how much information you want to capture about the exception itself.  If you just want the message, then calling `.ToString()` will be sufficient since that ends up giving you the message property from the exception object.  The MSDN site [lists different properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception_properties.aspx) that belong to the base exception class.  If you want to log any of these properties, then you will want the exception *class* and not just the message string.

Also note that different classes that inherit the base exception class provide additional information.  As an example, the [HttpException class provides additional properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception_properties.aspx).  That information could be useful depending on what you need to see to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 6):

One is an exception object, one is the string result of calling `ToString` on an exception object.

They are different types and have different information.

For logging purposes, there is little difference as the logger would normally call `ToString` on the exception object anyway.

However, it is better to centralize this - have the exception logger call `ToString` instead of doing this in every call site to the logger. It is more maintainable and opens you up for doing more things with the exceptions in the future if needed.

Answer (score 1):

An `exception` object will contain a lot more information than the result of the `.ToString()`. At the very least that information will be in a more useful format (ie you can get individual pieces easily).

If all you do in the logger is call `exception.ToString()` though without using anything else then currently it will be no real difference. However, passing the exception object is probably better for future proofing (ie if you start wanting some more properties of the exception).

For what its worth what `ToString` does is call the following overload passing `true` as the parameter:

```
Private Function ToString(ByVal needFileLineInfo As Boolean) As String
    Dim className As String
    Dim message As String = Me.Message
    If ((message Is Nothing) OrElse (message.Length <= 0)) Then
        className = Me.GetClassName
    Else
        className = (Me.GetClassName & ": " & message)
    End If
    If (Not Me._innerException Is Nothing) Then
        className = String.Concat(New String() { className, " ---> ", Me._innerException.ToString(needFileLineInfo), Environment.NewLine, "   ", Environment.GetRuntimeResourceString("Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack") })
    End If
    Dim stackTrace As String = Me.GetStackTrace(needFileLineInfo)
    If (Not stackTrace Is Nothing) Then
        className = (className & Environment.NewLine & stackTrace)
    End If
    Return className
End Function
```

As you can see it basically will output the class, message, innerexception.ToString() and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Exception object is different than .ToString(). It has vast variety of properties, also if you need to pass the message only, you can use `Ex.Message;`

Comment: I'd strongly discourage using only Ex.Message @Zo Has. You lose the stack trace. Although that might be OK in rare cases, generally the stack trace is valuable and worthy of preservation.